# Change Sprite Canvas Material color to another element's color

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I was wondering how to change the Sprite Canvas Material color

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
color: 0xffffff,
```

so that it would follow another element's color with a specific ID/class. I'm not sure how to achieve this since the CSS color system would be #FFFFFF whereas here it is 0xffffff.

I deleted the first question since I gained a bit more insight on this. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: remove "#", after that use {color: parseInt(YourColourString, 16)}

Comment: If I remove the # from my element's color ID/class then it wouldn't have any color.

Comment: remove `#` not from your element's color, but from a variable which contains a string with element's color

Comment: @prisoner849 To be frank I don't know how to exactly do that. I'm a self-taught coder so I don't have a firm grasp on complicated things such as three.js but I did research and tried with this `color: function changeColorAs() {
  var elementcol = document.getElementById("test"),
  elemstyle = window.getComputedStyle(element),
  bgcolor = elemstyle.getPropertyValue("color");
  hextodec = bgcolor.toHexString(16);` and I'm sure it's wrong but I didn't know where to start so yeah, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Color()` object has the `.setStyle ( style )` method, where `style — color as a CSS-style string`.

Let's imagine that you have several elements of "clicker" class

```
  <div class="clicker red"></div>
  <div class="clicker green"></div>
  <div class="clicker blue"></div>
  <div class="clicker white"></div>
```

with additional classes for colours:

```
.clicker {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

as you want them to react on clicking, you have to set event listeners, like so:

```
var clickers = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");
for(var i = 0; i < clickers.length; i++){
    var clicker = clickers[i];
    clicker.addEventListener("click", setColor);
}
```

note the `setColor` is a function you call when you click an element:

```
function setColor(e){
  var target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement; // get the element you've clicked
  var css = window.getComputedStyle(target); // get computed style of the element
  var color = css.backgroundColor; // get element's background color (it will be like "rgb(128,0,255)")
  spriteMaterial.color.setStyle(color); // apply this color to the material of sprites via the "setStyle" method
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/bgunns5t/) example (click the colourful circles to change the colour of the cube of sprites there)

Comment: [This](http://codepen.io/lexa-r/pen/jyOoLa) is my code with your added code, tweaked. The target element dynamically changes its color, so I want the sprite's material color to change and match the target element every time it changes on refresh. I'm not sure what went wrong with the code.

Comment: I've updated the answer (and fiddle), considering new information from your comment. Sorry, but I can't debug your code for you. Try to use your browser's console log to do it yourself. I just can give you an idea or advice with working example.

Comment: I understand but unfortunately, I don't even know where to begin with. I've opened the browser console log many times but the only error I can see is the console.log line being highlighted in the CanvasRenderer.js. I've added the console.log to my tweaked code but still nothing. Sorry if this is bothersome but I really am determined to learn and understand this.

Comment: The last update of the answer and fiddle. I've changed the renderer to `THREE.CanvasRenderer()`, built a cube of sprites, added `OrbitControls`. Note, that the `spriteMaterial` (which is `THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial()`) is a global variable, thus you can access it from any part of the script.